# Dataframe : add listed values in a new column from if else function

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I'm looking for assigned a category to my customer_id based on a condition. 
How to set values in a new columns from this function :

```
# customers categories based on rfm segmentation
cat = ["champion", "loyal", "big spenders", "almost lost", "hibernating", "lost cheap", "uncategorized"]

def customers_cat(rfm, f, m):
    if rfm == '444':
        return cat[0]
    if f == 4:
       return cat[1]
    if m == 4 :
       return cat[2]
    if rfm == '244':
        return cat[3]
    if rfm == '144':
        return cat[4]
    if rfm == '111':
        return cat[5]
    else:
        return cat[6]
```

What I would like : 
My dataframe df_cat get a new column df_cat['categories'] where values egals to cat list based on condition in the function.

```
df_cat['categories'] = customers_cat(df_cat['rfm_score'],
df_cat['f_score'],
df_cat['m_score'])
```

Error =>

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Right now you're comparing an entire series to a number in your function

Comment: i don't quite understand your `if else` logic

Comment: Maybe I should add previous code
Answer of Nihal allows to add values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will read dataframe row by row. `axis=1` if you want row by row, 
use:

```
df_cat['categories'] = df_cat.apply(lambda row: customers_cat(row['rfm_score'],row['f_score'],row['m_score']), axis=1)
```

if you are using only one column then you can use.

```
df_cat['categories'] = df_cat['rfm_score'].apply(lambda row: customers_cat(row), axis=0)
```